# Cannot inject entityManager in Weld & Seam 3

Tags: jpa-2.0, cdi, jboss-weld, jboss7.x, seam3

I'm getting started to Seam 3 and Weld. Now I'm struggling with the perstistence - the entityManager is not being injected.

Fist, I have set up a maven project from scratch (not generated). This project has two sub-modules:

- model: just contains the entities
- web: contains front-end (jsf) and beans (no EJB). this module depends on the model module.

So in the web module, i have my persistence.xml in `src/main/resources/META-INF`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!-- Persistence deployment descriptor for dev profile -->
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="allternative" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/allternativeDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"
                value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

then I have the class ApplicationInitializer:

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class ApplicationInitializer {

    @Produces
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="allternative")
    @Dependent
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Produces
    @PersistenceUnit(unitName="allternative")
    @Dependent
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

}
```

And the class CurrentUser:

```
@Named("currentUser")
@SessionScoped
public class CurrentUser implements Serializable {

    private boolean isLogin = false;

    @Inject
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Inject
    private Logger log;

    private User user;

    public CurrentUser() {
        this.user = null;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        log.info("getting user");
        if(this.user == null) {
            log.info("user is null, getting default from db");
            this.user = entityManager.find(User.class, "thobens"); // <- strange exception here
//          log.info("took user "+user.getUsername());
        }
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

when i call #{currentUser.user} I get the following strange exception:

```
16:57:04,768 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Error Rendering View[/index.xhtml]: javax.el.ELException: /index.xhtml: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't find a deployment unit named allternative at deployment "web.war"
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:88) [jsf-impl-2.1.3-b02-jbossorg-2.jar:2.1.3-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82) [jsf-impl-2.1.3-b02-jbossorg-2.jar:2.1.3-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:183) [jsf-impl-2.1.3-b02-jbossorg-2.jar:2.1.3-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:278) [richfaces-components-ui-4.0.0.Final.jar:]
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:181) [richfaces-components-ui-4.0.0.Final.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Beta1.jar:2.0.0.Beta1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1763) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Beta1.jar:2.0.0.Beta1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Beta1.jar:2.0.0.Beta1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Beta1.jar:2.0.0.Beta1]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:401) [jsf-impl-2.1.3-b02-jbossorg-2.jar:2.1.3-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131) [jsf-impl-2.1.3-b02-jbossorg-2.jar:2.1.3-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.application.PrettyViewHandler.renderView(PrettyViewHandler.java:163) [prettyfaces-jsf2-3.3.0.jar:]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Beta1.jar:2.0.0.Beta1]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Beta1.jar:2.0.0.Beta1]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Beta1.jar:2.0.0.Beta1]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121) [jsf-impl-2.1.3-b02-jbossorg-2.jar:2.1.3-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.3-b02-jbossorg-2.jar:2.1.3-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.3-b02-jbossorg-2.jar:2.1.3-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Beta1.jar:2.0.0.Beta1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:67) [weld-core-1.1.2.Final.jar:2011-07-26 15:02]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:118) [prettyfaces-jsf2-3.3.0.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.solder.servlet.exception.CatchExceptionFilter.doFilter(CatchExceptionFilter.java:65) [solder-impl-3.1.0.Beta3.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.solder.servlet.event.ServletEventBridgeFilter.doFilter(ServletEventBridgeFilter.java:72) [solder-impl-3.1.0.Beta3.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:139) [jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:388) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.NamingValve.invoke(NamingValve.java:57) [jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:49) [jboss-as-jpa-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:154) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:667) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:952) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [:1.6.0_20]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't find a deployment unit named allternative at deployment "web.war"
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.bootstrap.WeldJpaInjectionServices.getScopedPUName(WeldJpaInjectionServices.java:94) [jboss-as-weld-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.bootstrap.WeldJpaInjectionServices.resolvePersistenceContext(WeldJpaInjectionServices.java:59) [jboss-as-weld-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectEEFields(Beans.java:784) [weld-core-1.1.2.Final.jar:2011-07-26 15:02]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget$1$1.proceed(ManagedBean.java:181) [weld-core-1.1.2.Final.jar:2011-07-26 15:02]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:54) [weld-core-1.1.2.Final.jar:2011-07-26 15:02]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget$1.work(ManagedBean.java:176) [weld-core-1.1.2.Final.jar:2011-07-26 15:02]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$FixInjectionPoint.run(ManagedBean.java:142) [weld-core-1.1.2.Final.jar:2011-07-26 15:02]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget.inject(ManagedBean.java:170) [weld-core-1.1.2.Final.jar:2011-07-26 15:02]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:339) [weld-core-1.1.2.Final.jar:2011-07-26 15:02]
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:122) [weld-core-1.1.2.Final.jar:2011-07-26 15:02]
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:693) [weld-core-1.1.2.Final.jar:2011-07-26 15:02]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractReceiverBean.getReceiver(AbstractReceiverBean.java:84) [weld-core-1.1.2.Final.jar:2011-07-26 15:02]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ProducerField$1.produce(ProducerField.java:134) [weld-core-1.1.2.Final.jar:2011-07-26 15:02]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractProducerBean.create(AbstractProducerBean.java:361) [weld-core-1.1.2.Final.jar:2011-07-26 15:02]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.ee.EEResourceProducerField.createUnderlying(EEResourceProducerField.java:170) [weld-core-1.1.2.Final.jar:2011-07-26 15:02]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.ee.EEResourceProducerField.access$000(EEResourceProducerField.java:54) [weld-core-1.1.2.Final.jar:2011-07-26 15:02]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.ee.EEResourceProducerField$EEResourceCallable.call(EEResourceProducerField.java:80) [weld-core-1.1.2.Final.jar:2011-07-26 15:02]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.CallableMethodHandler.invoke(CallableMethodHandler.java:50) [weld-core-1.1.2.Final.jar:2011-07-26 15:02]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.2.Final.jar:2011-07-26 15:02]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:125) [weld-core-1.1.2.Final.jar:2011-07-26 15:02]
    at org.jboss.weldx.persistence.EntityManager$-1772293428$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.find(EntityManager$-1772293428$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.java) [weld-core-1.1.2.Final.jar:]
    at com.allternative.web.security.CurrentUser.getUser(CurrentUser.java:42) [classes:]
    at com.allternative.web.security.CurrentUser$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getUser(CurrentUser$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_20]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [:1.6.0_20]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_20]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_20]
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:302) [jboss-el-api_2.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176) [jsf-impl-2.1.3-b02-jbossorg-2.jar:2.1.3-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203) [jsf-impl-2.1.3-b02-jbossorg-2.jar:2.1.3-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:134) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:187) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:55) [weld-core-1.1.2.Final.jar:2011-07-26 15:02]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ELText.java:224) [jsf-impl-2.1.3-b02-jbossorg-2.jar:2.1.3-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextComposite.writeText(ELText.java:148) [jsf-impl-2.1.3-b02-jbossorg-2.jar:2.1.3-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:85) [jsf-impl-2.1.3-b02-jbossorg-2.jar:2.1.3-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 46 more
```

This occurs as soon i touch `entityManager`. When I annotate it with `@PersistenceContext` instead of `@Inject` this error occurs already at deployment.

I guess it has something to do with the persistence.xml not beeing processed, because

a) When I call `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("allternative").createEntityManager()`, I get an error saying that there is no such persistence unit.

b) I have `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` set to "update" (and also tried with "create"), but I'm getting no feedback that my entities are created in the DB (and running `show tables;` on mysql also results an empty set). I also don't get a hint if the persistence unit is created or not. The DataSource is available (and deployed by JBoss) and the db is created.

My beans.xml is locatex at `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/` (only in the web module):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:t="urn:java:org.jboss.seam.persistence.transaction"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
    <interceptors>
        <class>org.jboss.seam.faces.context.conversation.ConversationBoundaryInterceptor</class>
        <class>org.jboss.seam.transaction.TransactionInterceptor</class>
    </interceptors>

</beans>
```

and currently I have one entity (in the model module):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Length(min=6, max=32)
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    private String firstname;

    @NotNull
    private String lastname;

    @NotNull
    @Length(min=6, max=64)
    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String user) {
        this.username = user;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.username.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if(other == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if(!(other instanceof User)) {
            return false;
        }
        User otherUser = (User)other;
        String user = otherUser.getUsername();
        if(user == null || this.username == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return this.username.equals(user);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.username;
    }
}
```

I really don't get why this does not work. Can anyone help me, please?

Thanks in advance,

Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gotta punch my self in the face for this, i misspelled the name of the persistence.xml...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the `persistence.xml` must be present in the *ejb*-module (your packaging type of *model* is `ejb`, right?). In this directory `src/main/resources/META-INF`I also have an empty `beans.xml`.

I'm unsure about your `@ApplicationScoped ApplicationInitializer`. I think you are using this class to get an injectable `@EntityManager`, but I don't know if this is the recommended way (I hope this answer is). Instead of using the class `ApplicationInitializer` you can try the following in the *ejb* module: Create a class `MyRepository` to distinguish multiple persistence-units and a class `MyRepositoryProducer` to `@Produce` your `EntityManager`:

```
@Qualifier
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD,
          ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyRepository {}
```

and

```
public class MyRepositoryProducer
{
  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  @Produces
  @MyRepository
  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;
}
```

then you can inject your `EntityManager` in your `CurrentUser`-Bean with

```
@Inject @MyRepository private EntityManager em;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not using ejb at all, so my packaging is not ejb but war. From my understanding I should create this producer in the web module (which is packaged as war). This is basically what my ApplicationInitializer would do. Wouldn't MyRepositoryProducer need a @Named annotation to be processed? I'm just wondering because in Seam 2 you had to do that, otherwise no injection could be processed.

Comment: I have now created the RepositoryProducer and the @Qualifier annotation, but I'm still getting the same exception when I access the injected entityManager... And the tables in my database are still not created.

Comment: Can you explain *I'm not using ejb at all*? You have a `@Entity` Bean and wondering why your tables are not created. Can you please check your JBoss7 configuration with an example? I mentioned the archetype for this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332561

Comment: Sorry for late response. I'm not using the ejb means that I'm not using the EJB3 spec. Annotating a class with `@Entity` does not mean that it is an ejb, since its part of the JPA. That's why I have no ear project.

Comment: To answer your question about the packaging of the _model_ project: it is _jar_

Comment: I also noticed a Log entry saying `Preventing class org.jboss.seam.persistence.HibernatePersistenceProvider from being installed as bean due to @Veto annotation`. Am I missing a dependency or what does that message mean?

Comment: I also have this `@Veto` warning (along with several others).