# How to use Maven with EAR

Tags: java, maven, m2eclipse, ear

If i want to convert an EAR project a maven project , do  i need to add the module in the deployment assembly as maven dependency or just use the convert in m2eclipse without any further configuration.

Comment: Is it an eclipse project?

Comment: yes it is an eclipse project.

Answer (score 1):

Me personally I wouldn't attempt any kind of conversion of an existing project. I would add the poms, make sure that mvn clean install works on the command prompt and then create a new mavenized Eclipse project from the poms.

The main reason is that you current project settings are effectively wrong when you switch to Maven - the Maven poms are the truth and what feeds the Eclipse project setup, so you really do not want to make your life difficult and work against m2eclipse - let it do the project creation for you. Fresh.

Comment: But what do you do if you have an EAR project and want to convert to maven is there a need to add any thing to auto created pom

Comment: Again me personally: I wouldn't WANT generated poms. Create them by hand to make sure they are clean and what you actually want. Why do you want them generated? To not have to learn Maven? You're going to have to do that no matter what, or expect misery every time you change something.

Answer (score 1):

You can install `m2eclipse` and then do the following as well.

**Go to the `project menu` (right click on Package Explorer) > Configure > Convert to Maven Project**

Open the pom.xml and right-click and choose **Run As -> Maven Clean**. Similarly Choose **Run As -> Maven Install.**

Note : Please ensure that your eclipse project settings are correct and classpath libraries are not absolute and you don't have any project specific environment variables defined in your workspace. **Please take a backup of your project before you do this**.This is to ensure we don't mess up the current stable project configurations. Once m2eclipse generates the pom.xml for your project, you can update and make changes to it to
fully obtain a mavenized ear build. hope this helps

Comment: How to deal with module in deployment assembly in the pom file thats my question

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert your existing eclipse dependencies into Maven dependencies, you can try the JBoss Tools (JBT) Maven integration feature, which contains an experimental conversion wizard, plugged into m2e's conversion process : http://docs.jboss.org/tools/whatsnew/maven/maven-news-4.0.0.Beta1.html.

So, all you have to do is, as Keerthi explained, right-click on your project and Configure > Convert to Maven...

If your dependencies already are maven artifacts, it should work easily. If not, you'll need to convert them to Maven (if they're workspace projects) or make them available in your maven enterprise repository, before converting the EAR project.

JBT (requires Eclipse JavaEE) can be installed from http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/kepler/ or from the Eclipse Marketplace (See https://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/site/jboss%2520tools)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try creating new maven project with archetype selection of "jboss-javaee6-ear" and follow the similar structure for your project. Most probably you will need parent Pom and child poms per each module (ejb, war, jar etc). There are other few similar approach but almost all of them requires you to have mulitple POMs 
[maven-ear-plugin and JBoss AS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332561/maven-ear-plugin-and-jboss-as-7) 
You can also go through all the examples for maven ear plugin to find settings suitable for you 
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/ 
I ended up ditching ear for war :) single POM and even ditched the JBOss for tomcat/jetty :)